# How to use context

Tags: go, goroutine

For a personal project, I'm spawning an external process which hosts a REST API.
I only want to pass control back to the main thread once the external process has been initialized, which can be known by reading Stdout.

So I have created an `io.Writer` implementation which closes a channel once a certain criteria has been met.

```
type channelIOWriter struct {
    InitializedChannel chan bool
    isInitialized      bool
    buffer             string
}

func newChannelIOWriter() *channelIOWriter {
    retVal := new(channelIOWriter)
    retVal.InitializedChannel = make(chan bool)

    return retVal
}

func (writer *channelIOWriter) Write(data []byte) (int, error) {
    for _, b := range data {

        if b == '\n' {
            writer.buffer = *bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0))
            continue
        }

        writer.buffer.WriteByte(b)

        if strings.HasPrefix(writer.buffer.String(), "ChromeDriver was started successfully.") {
            if !writer.isInitialized {
                close(writer.InitializedChannel)
            }

            writer.isInitialized = true
        }
    }

    return len(data), nil
}
```

Next, I have the main function which, in a seperate goroutine, spawns the external process.
A wait is performed on the channel that's suposed to be closed by the `io.Writer` implementation.

```
func main() {
    writer := newChannelIOWriter()

    go func() {
        cmd := exec.Command("chromedriver", "--port=9009")
        cmd.Stdout = writer
        cmd.Start()
    }()

    <-writer.InitializedChannel

    fmt.Println("Control is passed back to the MAIN thread.")
}
```

According to the comments on the question, it seems to be better to use a context.
Anyone who can explain on how to use that?

Comment: Are you sure your `if strings.HasPrefix` ever succeeds? `Write` is not guaranteed to get all the bytes at once. Ideally, you should have a context with deadline that guarantees initialisation completes or fails within some reasonable timeout.

Comment: Hmm, good point.

Comment: It seems I can get it to work when using a bytes.Buffer to write the data into and than checking the contents of the buffer.

Would you mind posting an example with the usage of a context with deadline and timeout? Would really help.

Comment: You should wait on  <-writer.InitializedChannel with a timeout.  See the [time.After documentation](https://godoc.org/time#example-After) for an example.  Simplify the code by moving the contents of the goroutine to the main function. The goroutine is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stripped out all unnecessary detail and demo how context with deadline works

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

type example struct {
    cancel context.CancelFunc
}

func (e *example) Write(data []byte) (int, error) {
    defer e.cancel()
    return len(data), nil
}
func main() {
    deadline := time.Now().Add(5 * time.Second)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), deadline)
    writer := &example{
        cancel: cancel,
    }

    go func() {
        cmd := exec.Command("ls", ".")
        cmd.Stdout = writer
        _ = cmd.Start()
    }()

    <-ctx.Done()

    fmt.Println("Control is passed back to the MAIN thread.", ctx.Err())
}
```